# How to send a link to an application, like Spotify does

Tags: c++, winapi, hyperlink, protocols, wtl

When we save a level in our editor, we create a log file of any errors it contains. These consist basically of an error message and a path that allows the user to find the erronous item in a tree view.

What I want is to make that path a link, something like
< a href="editor://path/to/gameobject" > Click to see object in editor< /a >

The SO questions I've seen regarding this seems to point to this msdn page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx

But from what I can tell, it will spawn a new instance of the application. What I want to do is to simply "call" our editor somehow. One way to do it, I guess, is to spawn it, and in the beginning check if there's already an instance running, and if so, send the commandline to it.

Is that the best way to do it? If so, any ideas on how to do it best? What are otherwise some ways that this could be done?

Also: does the msdn solution work across browsers? Our editor runs in Windows only, but people use IE, Fx, GC and Opera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the link to work in any viewer, yes, registering a protocol handler is the best way.

As for launching the editor, you could implement it as an [out-of-process COM server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680076.aspx), but if you've already got command line parsing sorted, you might as well use [a window message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011.aspx) or named pipe to pass that to the editor.  If you're sending a window message, you could use [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx) (with a unique class name) to check for a running instance.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you solved it already, by checking for a previous instance.

I would be surprised if the OS takes upon it to somehow "stamp" the association with data telling it to separate programs that should run multiple times from programs that should not.

Comment: Make you application check for a previous instance if available and pass on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it. Basically, there are two parts. Or three.

First, the app needs to register itself in the registry, like this. It took some googling to find out how to use the windows register functions, but they were pretty straightforward. By adding this to the registry, your application will launch when a link with your custom url protocol is clicked.

Secondly, the app needs to detect that it's been started from a browser. Obviously quite trivial, just check the command line for "/uri" or however you chose to customize it.

Third, you don't actually want to *start* your application - it should already be running! Instead, when you've detected that you got started from a hyperlink, you need to detect if another instance of the application is already running. After that, you need to pass the command line to it. Here's how I did it:

```
bool ShouldContinueStartEditor( const std::string& command_line )
{
    // Check if this instance was spawned from a web browser
    if ( command_line.find( "/uri" ) != std::string::npos )
    {
        // Try to find other instance of JustEdit
        HWND wnd = FindWindow( "AV_MainFrame", NULL );
        if ( wnd )
        {
            COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
            NEditorCopyData::SCommandLine data_to_copy;

            strncpy( data_to_copy.m_CommandLine, command_line.c_str(), sizeof(data_to_copy.m_CommandLine) - 2 );
            cds.dwData = NEditorCopyData::ECommandLine; // function identifier
            cds.cbData = sizeof( data_to_copy );  // size of data
            cds.lpData = &data_to_copy;           // data structure

            SendMessage( wnd, WM_COPYDATA, NULL, (LPARAM) (LPVOID) &cds );
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

"AV_Mainframe" is the name of the hwnd. If you happen to be using WTL, you can declare it like this.

```
DECLARE_FRAME_WND_CLASS("AV_MainFrame", IDR_MAINFRAME)
```

Now, in your window class, you need to handle the WM_COPYDATA message like this:

```
MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_COPYDATA, OnCopyData);
LRESULT OnCopyData(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/);


LRESULT CMainFrame::OnCopyData(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{
 PCOPYDATASTRUCT cds = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT) lParam;
 if ( cds->dwData == NEditorCopyData::ECommandLine )
 {
  NEditorCopyData::SCommandLine* command_line = static_cast( cds->lpData );

  const char* internal_path = strstr( command_line->m_CommandLine, "/uri" );
  if ( internal_path != NULL )
  {
   // Do your thang
  }
 }

 return 0;
}
```

And that's pretty much all there's to it. Oh, this is what the copy data namespace looks like:

```
namespace NEditorCopyData
{
 enum ECopyDataMessages
 {
  ECommandLine = 0
 };

 struct SCommandLine
 {
  char m_CommandLine[512];
 };

}
```